# Calculating the determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant

During the past week, I have been trying to calculate the determinant of the following matrix:
[image]

Here is what I have tried so far. I replaced each row starting from the thrid with the difference of the one before and it. In this way i transformed it into an almost diagonal matrix but still if I try to expand it through the elements of the first column I always get almost diagonal minors and it doesnt work. :(

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

how about
$$
38\ n!(n+1)!
$$
?

Note that I take
$n=0$ for a $2\times 2$ matrix. For example,
$n=0$
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -8&6\\-9&2\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $\text{det}=38$

$n=1$
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -8&6&6\\-9&2&2\\-9&2&4\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $\text{det}=76=38.2$

$n=2$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}-8&6&6&6\\-9&2&2&2\\-9&2&4&2\\-9&2&2&8\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $\text{det}=456=28.2.6$

$n=3$: $$\begin{pmatrix}-8&6&6&6&6\\-9&2&2&2&2\\-9&2&4&2&2\\-9&2&2&8&2\\-9&2&2&2&14\end{pmatrix}$$, with $\text{det}=5472=38.6.24$.

etc.

Comment: That looks true but how do I prove it by induction!?

Comment: @yooleesun no idea, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Elaboration on the attempt so-far:

By your row operations, we end up with the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
-8 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & \cdots & 6\\
-9 & 2 + n & 2 & 2 & 2&  \cdots & 2\\
\hline
0 & -n & 1 \cdot 2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 \cdot 2 & 2 \cdot 3 &  0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots &&&\ddots & \ddots \qquad\ddots&&\vdots\\
\\
\\
0&&&&&&0\\
0&\cdots&0&0&&-(n-2)(n-1) & (n-1)n
}
$$
which must have the same determinant.

Comment: Yes but calculating this determinant is not easier than calculating original I think